# Using Html.DisplayFor in mvc with templates

Tags: asp.net-mvc, templates, html-helper

I have a model

```
public class Person {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

and a Simple View

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IList<Site.Models.Person>>" %>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
</head>
<body>
    <% for (int i = 0 ; i < Model.Count ; i++) {  %>
        <%: Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i])%>
    <% } %>
</body>
</html>
```

With a Partial View

```
 <%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Site.Models.Person>" %>
 <h1>A person</h1>
 <div>Name: <%: Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Name)%></div>
 <div>Age: <%: Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Age)%></div>
```

and single Controller

```
public ActionResult Index () {
        Person p1 = new Person { Age = 18 , Name = "jon" };
        Person p2 = new Person { Age = 23 , Name = "bob" };

        return View(new List<Person> { p1 , p2 });
    }
```

The Displayfor in the view should show each person displayed with the Template specified in the partial view, but it is not. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The partial view name must be `Person.ascx` placed in `shared\DisplayTemplates` folder

Comment: That did the trick. I guess when I was reading this post http://haacked.com/archive/2010/05/05/asp-net-mvc-tabular-display-template.aspx I didnt read it well enough. Thanks :)